# Google Ad Manager AdListener#onAdClicked() callback doesn't trigger

Tags: android, ads, google-ad-manager

Good afternoon. I'm trying to implement Google Ad Manager to the project (not AdMob) to render the advertising content.

According to my needs, I'm using Native ads (not Banner) with the  *AdSize.FLUID.*
For some reason when I'm trying to set *AdListener* to *PublisherAdView.
onAdClicked()* callback doesn't trigger (other callbacks works perfectly).
Has somebody faced that strange issue and how have you solved it?

P.S. *onAdClicked()* callback works if I load advertising content via *AdLoader.Builder()*, but I cannot use it due to the project structure.

P.P.S  I'm using the following version of the play services ads version

```gradle
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
```

```java
  PublisherAdView publisherAdView = new PublisherAdView(context);
        publisherAdView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        publisherAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize.FLUID);
        publisherAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                Log.e("!", "onAdFailedToLoad: ");
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                Log.e("!", "onAdOpened: " );
                super.onAdOpened();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Log.e("!", "onAdLoaded: " );
                super.onAdLoaded();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                super.onAdClicked();
                Log.e("!", "onAdClicked: ");
            }
        });

        PublisherAdRequest.Builder builder = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder();
        publisherAdView.loadAd(builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've didn't find how to solve this issue.
I had some restrictions because of project structure, so I've wrapped Google ads view
with a custom view (nothing special, just a container with ad view and placeholder + some methods for building ad, and changing placeholder visibility).

With this solution, I'm able to use AdLoader.Builder().